# $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is a field or just an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

In Steps in Commutative Algebra of Sharp, Problem 3.24 implies $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$  is an integral domain. But is it a field? Since the ideal is irreducible, I can't find a bigger ideal.

Comment: $(x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz)$ is a bigger proper ideal.

Comment: $x^2 = 0$ so it has non-zero zero divisors, hence it is not an integral domain and therefore not a field. EDIT: By looking at Problem 3.24 in Sharp's book it looks like he is considering the the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and not $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2,y^2, z^2)$. Is that also what you intended?

Comment: My bad. Sorry you guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal $I=(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is homogeneous so the ring $\mathbb R[x,y,z]/I$ is a graded ring, with degrees in $\mathbb N_0$. In particular, only its elements of degree $0$ —which are the scalars— can be invertible. Since the ring is not just $\mathbb R$ (for example, its homogeneous component of degre $1$ is $3$-dimensional) it is not a field.

Answer (score 3):

You should take $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ which is larger than $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.